# Add default value to a field

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-form

My scenario:

I have a list and I want to create a new item, the form used to create a new item opens up and I have a field name Administrator there and by default, I want the username of the person creating that item to appear.

**Note** I do not want to rename the created By field

Also, note we are using a community site, I don't find the Add default value to a column in library settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that worked for me without any bug.

```
<script>  
    $(document).ready(function() {  

        var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;  


        function GetCurrentUser() {  

            var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";  

            var requestHeaders = {  
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"  
            };  

            $.ajax({  

                url: requestUri,  

                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",  

                headers: requestHeaders,  

                success: onSuccess,  

                error: onError  

            });  

        }  

        function onSuccess(data, request) {  

            var loginName = data.d.Title;  

            SetUserFieldValue("your field name", loginName);  

        }  

        function onError(error) {  

            alert(error);  

        }  

        function SetUserFieldValue(fieldName, userName) {  

            var _PeoplePicker = $("div[title='" + fieldName + "']");  

            var _PeoplePickerTopId = _PeoplePicker.attr('id');  

            var _PeoplePickerEditer = $("input[title='" + fieldName + "']");  

            _PeoplePickerEditer .removeAttr('placeholder');

            _PeoplePickerEditer.val(userName);  

            var _PeoplePickerOject = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[_PeoplePickerTopId];  

            _PeoplePickerOject.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);  

        }  

        GetCurrentUser();  

    });  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could insert script editor/content editor webpart to your list form, and init the field value by javascript.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
        function GetCurrentUser() {
            var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";
            var requestHeaders = { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" };
            $.ajax({
                url: requestUri,
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                headers: requestHeaders,
                success: onSuccess,
                error: onError
            });
        }
        function onSuccess(data, request) {
            var loginName = data.d.Title;
            SetUserFieldValue("people", loginName);
        }
        function onError(error) {
            //alert(error);
        }
        function SetUserFieldValue(fieldName, userName) {
            var _PeoplePicker = $("div[title='" + fieldName + "']");
            var _PeoplePickerTopId = _PeoplePicker.attr('id');
            var _PeoplePickerEditor = $("input[title='" + fieldName + "']");
            _PeoplePickerEditer.val(userName);
            var _PeoplePickerObject = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[_PeoplePickerTopId];
            _PeoplePickerObject.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);
        }
        GetCurrentUser();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: exactly the code am been using,note i replace fieldName correctly,but  i dont see the name appearing in the required field also,note i dont get any error.

Comment: ok it works but note the variable _PeoplePickerEditer  should be 
 _PeoplePickerEditor..now in the field the whole username doesnt show up only 5 letters!!!